# Preventing downloading file from a webpage

Tags: html, audio, browser

I have a webpage with an audio player - normally the code would look like this

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto">
    <source src="http://the_full_path/file_name.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I want people to be able to listen to the file using the player without **being able to download** the file its playing. These are the first steps I took:

1. was adding `controlsList="nodownload"` to the player
2. disabling right click `oncontextmenu="return false"`

The problem: from any browser going to menu 'view-> page source' or clicking F12/Cmd+u will show the code thus the link will be reviled.

How can I achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: It's practically impossible to keep a determined user from downloading a resource that they receive client side. It's like trying to keep someone from saving a picture from your website by disabling right clicking. A determined user will just open the dev tools and save that way or take a screenshot.

Comment: @zero298 we agree thats exactly the problem I wrote - I'm looking for innovative out of the box ideas not stating the obvious.

Comment: @zero298 and obviously there is a way to do it because dropbox has a feature in its pro account that disables download of shared link

Answer (score 0):

'and obviously there is a way to do it'
No there's not !
@zero298 answer is perfectly right(any resaerch you will do will said the same and you see your question is commonly asked for years with same answer.

All stuff you can do can easily be override because in order to use a file client side the file is download on client(cache) in order to be use by browser in local place.
Look to how WWW work and you'll understand better i think:

web server send(upload) HTML and others files related to client who get it(download) for use.
That's root of a network and can't be otherwise. If you need anything to be shared on a network you've to send it. So you can see/use(an get) a file who is not shared nor block a file once it is send.